# Problem adding a Ternary Operator on some Jquery code

Tags: jquery, ternary-operator

I have some jquery code which displays a hidden div on the DOM depending on whether the checkbox is clicked or not. The value of the checkbox also change to 1. I want to add a **ternary operator** to change the value to zero if the input is not clicked.

Please assist?

```
$("#card").click(function(){
    $("#card").val("1");
    $("#cardDeck").slideToggle("slow", "swing");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `is(':checked')` to check if checkbox is checked or not like below.

```js
$("#card").click(function() {
  $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val("1") : $(this).val("0");
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="card" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#card').change(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).attr("checked")?"1":"0")
});
```